# Как рассчитать координаты второй точки на карте?

Tags: java, математика, карты

У меня есть координаты первой точки на карте, есть расстояние между точками и есть градусы поворота относительно сторон света (с компаса). Подскажите пожалуйста как рассчитать координаты второй точки на карте?

Я пробовал взять формулу для нахождения расстояния между точками и перестроить ее, но я не могу понять как использовать градусы поворота и в конце концов запутался окончательно.

Comment: Под градусами поворота азимут имеется в виду?

Comment: В любом случае, вам не нужно перестраивать никакую формулу расстояния между точками. Вам нужно просто найти координаты вектора AB, заданные углом и длиной, после чего прибавить их к координатам точки A.

Comment: @EzikBro а как быть с тем что земля не плоская?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ нужно отталкиваться от входных данных и уж точно не ковыряться в формулах расстояния. Хотя я слишком категоричен в этом плане, ковыряться может и придется, но только тогда, когда автор вопроса его уточнит.

Comment: @EzikBro какая нибудь haversine формула подойдет, наверное..

Comment: @EzikBro, да, я имел в виду азимут.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Смотрим [сюда](https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) в раздел `Destination point given distance and bearing from start point`:

```
φ2 = asin( sin φ1 ⋅ cos δ + cos φ1 ⋅ sin δ ⋅ cos θ )
λ2 = λ1 + atan2( sin θ ⋅ sin δ ⋅ cos φ1, cos δ − sin φ1 ⋅ sin φ2 )
where   
φ is latitude, 
λ is longitude, 
θ is the bearing (clockwise from north),
δ is the angular distance d/R; 
d being the distance travelled, 
R the earth’s radius
```